# Finding equilibrium in a predator prey system

Tags: calculus

Using predator prey system

$\frac{dR}{dt}=6R\:-2RW$

$\frac{dW}{dt}=-4W\:+5RW$

$When\:the\:system\:is\:equilibrium\:with\:W\ne 0,\:R\:\ne 0\:then\:RW\:=?$

Apologize for formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assuming $R,W \neq 0$, you can safely divide by them. Dividing $6R-2RW=0$ by $R$, you get $6-2W=0$ or $W=3$. Substitute that into the second equation to find $R$.

Comment: So simple... :O

Comment: Substitution is not useful to find R.

Comment: @Did I don't see what you mean. You have $W=3$, so by substituting, you get $-12+15R=0$. abel did this last step explicitly.

Comment: The second equation reads W(5R-4)=0 hence, unless W=0, the value of W is not needed to find R.

Comment: @Did Sure, you could do the division procedure in the second equation if you want. That doesn't invalidate what I said.

Comment: ?? You think the value of W is useful to compute the value of R? Well...

Comment: @Did Yes, the solution to the second equation turns out not to depend on the value of $W$, because you can perform the same division procedure in the second equation to find $R$ as I used in the first equation to find $W$. But you can still find $W$ in the first equation by division (or factorization) and substitute into the second to find $R$. It doesn't *hurt* to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the non trivial special solutions where $w = constant, r = constant.$  that is $$r \neq 0, w \neq 0, 2r(3 - w) = 0 \text{ and } w(-4 + 5r)=0 $$ that is $$ w = 3, r = \frac 45.$$

Comment: You made some arithmetic errors.

Comment: @Ian,  thanks, i sure did. fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

"When the derivatives are 0 and it's an equation, use Cramer and some determination!" (It's a linear equation, solve for R and W and multiply them together)

"I like the rhyme because it's sublime"

Comment: Sublime, perhaps. Offtopic, surely.

Comment: @Did actually the rhyme answers her question, and I explicitly answer so sorry you find rhyming answers off topic :(

Comment: You "explicitly answer"... what? The question? I do not think so.